# How to enable android emulator sound on windows 10 with usb soundcard?

Tags: android, windows, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

I've been working in an android app and recently I realized that I can't get any sound from the emulator, not even from youtube app.

I'm  using windows 10 64 bits, usb audio interface and visual studio code but I have installed the avd manager from android studio. I have created new emulators with and without snapshot option checked, because I read that it might cause issues but it doesn't work. Microphone input works but audio output don't.

I've checked the windows settings and it apparently recognize the emulator but de sound controller is disabled.

[image]

This is the information of one of my emulators.

> Name: Pixel_4_API_29
>
> CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
>
> Path: C:\Users\Juan.android\avd\Pixel_4_API_29_1.avd
>
> Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 29)
>
> Skin: pixel_4
>
> SD Card: 512M
>
> fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:
>
> runtime.network.speed: full
>
> hw.accelerometer: yes
>
> hw.device.name: pixel_4
>
> hw.lcd.width: 1080
>
> hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
>
> image.androidVersion.api: 29
>
> tag.id: google_apis_playstore
>
> hw.mainKeys: no
>
> hw.camera.front: emulated
>
> avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 4 API 29
>
> hw.gpu.mode: auto
>
> hw.ramSize: 1536
>
> PlayStore.enabled: true
>
> fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
>
> hw.cpu.ncore: 4
>
> hw.keyboard: yes
>
> hw.sensors.proximity: yes
>
> hw.dPad: no
>
> hw.lcd.height: 2280
>
> vm.heapSize: 256
>
> skin.dynamic: yes
>
> hw.device.manufacturer: Google
>
> hw.gps: yes
>
> hw.audioInput: yes
>
> image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\
>
> showDeviceFrame: yes
>
> hw.camera.back: virtualscene
>
> AvdId: Pixel_4_API_29
>
> hw.lcd.density: 440
>
> hw.arc: false
>
> hw.device.hash2: MD5:6b5943207fe196d842659d2e43022e20
>
> fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
>
> fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
>
> hw.trackBall: no
>
> hw.battery: yes
>
> hw.sdCard: yes
>
> tag.display: Google Play
>
> runtime.network.latency: none
>
> disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
>
> hw.sensors.orientation: yes
>
> avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
>
> hw.gpu.enabled: yes

P.D I also tried with genymotion and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking at the one thing i didn't have looked, it turns out the issue was caused by the usb audio interface drivers, I didn't check that before beacaue everything was working fine and I could use the microphone through the audio interface with the emulators. I updated the audio drivers and got the sound output working.